# SUM total numbers by day?

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, sql-server-2014

If I have a database with two columns, `Date` and a `Number`, with multiple `Number` entries per `Date`.

How can I add a column that shows the total `Number` for the `Date` listed?

So if I have four entries for 05/09/2017, with values 2, 4, 3, 8, all four entries for that day should also have a column showing 17.

Comment: which version of sql-server are you using?

Comment: SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on a SQL Server version 2012 and above, use the `SUM` window function.

```
select date,number,sum(number) over(partition by date) as total
from tablename
```

Otherwise use

```
select t1.date,t1.number,t2.total
from tablename t1
join (select date,sum(number) as total from tablename group by date) t2 on t1.date=t2.date
```

Comment: Only after the 3rd of 4th read did I understand the question +1 for the solution and understanding the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT datecolumn,SUM(number) AS total FROM tablename GROUP BY DATE(datecolumn)
```